# CSS <img> tag not applying parent div class css style

Tags: css, image

Can anyone explain to me why are my images of left and right arrow not taking any css modifications which are done in their  class?

HTML

```
<div class="carousel-controls">
    <div class="carousel-prev"><a href="#" >
          <img src="http://localhost:4316/images/Left.png" alt="Previous"/></a></div>
    <div class="carousel-next"><a href="#">
          <img src="http://localhost:4316/images/Right.png" alt="Next" /></a></div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
#waterwheel-carousel-default .carousel-controls .carousel-prev {
position:absolute;
bottom:190px;
left:180px;
height:30px;
width:30px;
border:0px solid black;
}

#waterwheel-carousel-default .carousel-controls .carousel-next {
position:absolute;
bottom:190px;
right:150px;
height:30px;
width:30px;
border:0px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply particular styles to the `img` element itself.

For example, if your issue is that a border is appearing on the images, you need to do:

```
#waterwheel-carousel-default .carousel-controls img {
   border:0;
}
```

Notice I've not included `.carousel-prev` or `.carousel-next` in the selector, so that this rule will apply to both

Comment: So it is not necessary that the height and width which i have given to div class will apply to my image class?

Comment: @mabus44 No, you need to apply the styles to the element itself. Elements do not inherit their parent element's styles.

Answer (score 2):

You should target the `image` like this

```
#waterwheel-carousel-default .carousel-controls .carousel-prev img
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mj33p/)**

Answer (score 1):

Cause you designed the div, not the img tag.
You should add

```
#waterwheel-carousel-default .carousel-controls .carousel-prev img {
...
}

#waterwheel-carousel-default .carousel-controls .carousel-next img {
...
}
```

Comment: So it is not necessary that the height and width which i have given to div class will apply to my image class? –

Comment: It is required to give height and width to the div because its position is absolute. Position absolute require width and height. But you will have to add height and width to images separately.